# Number base conversation to/from base 85

Tags: javascript, numbers, converters, radix

I'm trying to apply the [algorithm of number conversion](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/%7Eram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html) using JavaScript. I set the base as a unique characters string with length 85. and I have written two functions like the following to convert from base 85 to base 10 (decimal) and vice versa from decimal to base 85:

```
numBase1 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPUQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqurstvwxyz~[]{}:.;!@#$%^&*()_-+=/';

function baseToDec(num, stem){
    
    n = num.length;
    b = stem.length;
    out = 0;
    for (i =0; i < num.length; i++){
        n--;
        out = out + (stem.indexOf(num[i])*(Math.pow(b,n)));               
      }
    return out;
}

function decToBase(num, stem){  
    const newBase = stem.length;
    let out = '';
    i=0;
    while(num > 0){
        let devide = num/newBase;
        let result = Math.floor(devide);
        let remind = devide - result;
        num = result;
        console.log(i+'>',num,devide,remind, newBase,Math.round(remind * newBase),stem[Math.round(remind * newBase)], Math.floor(devide))
        out = stem[Math.round(remind * newBase)]+out;
        i++
    }
    return out;
}
integ = baseToDec('Facebook.com6',numBase1)
console.log(integ,'****');
console.log(decToBase(integ,numBase1));
```

The issue here, at some point, it looks like dividing on 85 to convert the decimal to base 85, it looks like dividing on 1.
It only works correctly with numbers of base 85 that not exceed 8 characters length. The 9th character returned with mistaken character, while 10th and up returned with the first number of the base 85 i.e. `0`

Here is the copy of console:

```
2.1946274146286338e+24 **** nb-converter.js:53:9
0> 2.5819146054454515e+22 2.5819146054454515e+22 0 85 0 0 2.5819146054454515e+22 nb-converter.js:46:17
1> 303754659464170770000 303754659464170770000 0 85 0 0 303754659464170770000 nb-converter.js:46:17
2> 3573584228990244400 3573584228990244400 0 85 0 0 3573584228990244400 nb-converter.js:46:17
3> 42042167399885224 42042167399885224 0 85 0 0 42042167399885224 nb-converter.js:46:17
4> 494613734116296 494613734116296.75 0.75 85 64 ] 494613734116296 nb-converter.js:46:17
5> 5818985107250 5818985107250.541 0.541015625 85 46 k 5818985107250 nb-converter.js:46:17
6> 68458648320 68458648320.588234 0.5882339477539062 85 50 o 68458648320 nb-converter.js:46:17
7> 805395862 805395862.5882353 0.5882352590560913 85 50 o 805395862 nb-converter.js:46:17
8> 9475245 9475245.435294118 0.43529411777853966 85 37 b 9475245 nb-converter.js:46:17
9> 111473 111473.4705882353 0.4705882353009656 85 40 e 111473 nb-converter.js:46:17
10> 1311 1311.4470588235295 0.4470588235294599 85 38 c 1311 nb-converter.js:46:17
11> 15 15.423529411764706 0.42352941176470615 85 36 a 15 nb-converter.js:46:17
12> 0 0.17647058823529413 0.17647058823529413 85 15 F 0 nb-converter.js:46:17
Facebook]0000
```

I also tried a [PHP implementation](https://ideone.com/ZyXJdb) and it returned the same result.

I'm not sure if this issue is due to the decimal number is very big?! `2.1946274146286338e+24` or not. Is there any solution, or it is hardware or OS boundaries?

Comment: Javascript's max number value is 9007199254740991.
Then you need to use bigInt.
So the function might be correct. Didn't try that...

Comment: I have tried to use BigInt but I got `Uncaught TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number` from `devide = BigInt(num)/BigInt(newBase)`

Comment: Because newBase must be BigInt as well I guess...
1000n/1000 will throw this error... 1000n/1000n won't (which is the same as BigInt(1000)/BigInt(1000) = 1n)